# My javascriptcode is working when i put alert.I need to Display time in Counter Format(Seconds decreasing way)

Tags: javascript

My javascriptcode is working fine when i put alert.I need to Display time in Counter Format(Second decreasing way). Please help me in resolving this issue

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

window.onload = function () {
    //alert("request>>>");
    var count = 0;
    var start_actual_time  =  document.getElementById("timerStartTime").value;
    var end_actual_time    =  document.getElementById("timerEndTime").value;
    start_actual_time = new Date(start_actual_time);
    var start_actual_time1 = new Date(start_actual_time.getTime());
    start_actual_time1 = new Date(start_actual_time1);
    var end_actual_time1 = new Date(end_actual_time);
    var hours =end_actual_time1.getHours()- start_actual_time1.getHours();
     var minutes = end_actual_time1.getMinutes() - start_actual_time1.getMinutes();
     var seconds = end_actual_time1.getSeconds()- start_actual_time1.getSeconds();
    seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
    //alert ("seconds >>." +seconds);
    timer(seconds);

};


    function timer(seconds) {
        alert("calling timer");
        var s1 = Number(seconds);
        var hours = Math.floor(s1 / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor(s1 % 3600 / 60);
        var s = Math.floor(s1 % 3600 % 60);
        //alert("sec1" + s);
     display = document.querySelector('#time');
     var formatted = ((hours < 10)?("0" + hours):hours) + ":" + ((minutes < 10)?("0" + minutes):minutes) + ":" + ((s < 10)?("0" + s):s)
    display.textContent =  formatted ; 
     seconds = seconds - 1;
     timer(seconds);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written creates a

> too much recursion

exception for me.

Therefore I have avoided recursive invokes and used javascript [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){ timer(); }, 1000);
```

When your seconds reach zero, timer is stopped:

```
if (seconds == -1){
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
```

Link to working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ggspruf/2/